# How do i divide my mapped data in pages and place footers on all pages in react-to-print

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-to-print

I am using react-to-print to generate an invoice in which the table data is being mapped. As the mapped content increases it pushes down the footer with no proper placement. I want to place the footer on every page and I also want to show the page number there. How can I do this?

I have been stuck and have tried different CSS properties like `absolute` and `fixed` placement of the footer but obviously they are not working. Obviously this issue wont be solved by CSS alone.

```html
<div className="invoice__preview bg-white p-5 rounded-2xl border-4 border-blue-200  ">
    <ReactToPrint
        trigger={() => (
            <button className="bg-blue-500 ml-5 text-white font-bold py-2 px-8 rounded hover:bg-blue-600 hover:text-white transition-all duration-150 hover:ring-4 hover:ring-blue-400">
                Print / Download
            </button>
        )}
        content={() => componentRef.current}
    />
    <div ref={componentRef} className="py-5 px-8 flex flex-col min-h-full relative">
        <div>
            <div className=" flex justify-between my-5">
                <article className=" flex items-start justify-start">
                    <ul>
                        <li className="p-1 ">
                            <span className="font-bold">Location:</span> {location}
                        </li>
                        <li className="p-1 ">
                            <span className="font-bold">To:</span> {rowData.firstname + ' ' + rowData.lastname}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </article>
                <article className=" flex flex-col gap-2 items-start justify-end rounded-lg border border-black px-3 py-3">
                    <h2 className=" font-bold">Statements of Accounts (Period)</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li className=" ">
                          <span className="">From Date:</span> {fromDate}
                        </li>
                        <li className=" ">
                          <span className="">To Date:</span> {toDate}
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </article>
            </div>

            <table width="100%" className="mb-10 ">
                <thead>
                    <tr className="bg-gray-100 p-1 py-2 text-base text-black border-t border-b border-black uppercase w-full font-semibold">
                        <td className="font-bold">DATE</td>
                        <td className="font-bold">DOC NO</td>
                        <td className="font-bold">NARRATION</td>
                        <td className="font-bold">DEBIT</td>
                        <td className="font-bold">credit</td>
                        <td className="font-bold">balance</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {clientData && clientData.length > 0 ? (
                    <tbody>
                        <tr className=" h-10 font-bold rounded-xl border border-black">
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Opening Balance as on  {formatDate(new Date(fromDate))}</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>{clientData[0].Balance}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {clientData.map(({ date, docid, description, debit, credit, Balance }, index) => {

                        const formattedDate = formatDate(date);

                        return (
                            <tr key={docid} className="h-10">
                            <td>{formattedDate}</td>
                            <td>{docid}</td>
                            <td>{description}</td>
                            <td>{debit}</td>
                            <td>{credit}</td>
                            <td>{Balance}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                        })}

                        <tr className="h-10 font-bold rounded-xl border border-black">
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Transaction Totals:</td>
                        <td className="underline">{Math.round(clientData.reduce((total, { debit }) => total + parseFloat(debit || 0), 0))}</td>
                        <td className="underline">{Math.round(clientData.reduce((total, { credit }) => total + parseFloat(credit || 0), 0))}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    ) : (
                    <p className="mx-auto">No data available</p>
                    )}
            </table>

        </div>

        <footer className= " mt-auto footer border-t-2 border-gray-300 pb-5">
            <div className=" w-full flex justify-evenly pt-4 pb-14 px-5 border-b border-gray-300 mb-2 text-base">
                <p>Prepared By</p>
                <p>Approved By</p>
                <p>Salesman</p>
                <p className=" ">Reciever's Name & Signature </p>
                <p>Store Keeper</p>

            </div>
            <ul className="flex flex-wrap items-center gap-2 justify-center">
                <li>
                    <span className="font-bold">Email:</span> {"arcoglassqatar@gmail.com"}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span className="font-bold">Tel:</span> {""}<span className="ml-1 font-bold">-Fax:</span> {""}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span className="font-bold">P.O Box:</span> {" "}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p className="text-center px-5 mt-4 text-xs ">
            Thankyou for your purchase!
        </p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```